# Ranking based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to rank the clients based on fees. As I've shown in below table, in `column A` I have the country and `column B` the client name. So I want to find the Ranking in `column D` based on fee has been charged in `column C`. I have over 20K clients and I have tried to do it in Pivot table but it does not make a clear ranking for me because of the two criteria listing.

Which combination of formulas would solve this problem?

My table;

```
    A          B           C         D
1   Country   N-Client    Fees      Rank
2   Belgium   A Company   $720       
3   Canada    A Company   $210       
4   Belgium   B Company   $1300      
5   Canada    A Company   $500       
6   Canada    C Company   $600
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin  I am sorry, I've just elaborated the request.

Comment: Is there *any* reason why you can't simply sort the table on the values in `C`?

Comment: Did you try the RANK function?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting up a helper column then a rank column.  Set helper column row 2 to the following then copy down the sheet so the B2 at the end gets incremented to b3,b4 etc...:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

Then set a rank column (starting with row 2 and copying down) with the following replacing D:D with the column you choose above for the helper subtotal column:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE(D:D,ROW()-1),D:D,0),2))&" "&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE(D:D,ROW()-1),D:D,0),1))
```

You should end up with your ranked column with the highest paying company+country at the top and working down.

Edit: hmm this does result in duplicate entries.  You could copy your rank column, paste(special)-values somewhere then do a duplicate removal on it.